# Is there a way to change the viewing size of artboards in pdf?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf

I am creating a stationery set in illustrator, consisting of a letterhead, an envelope and a business card. When I save it as a pdf, the artboards do not align to the same margins. What I want to accomplish is, all my artboards having the same width in pdf format. However, I don't want to change the actual width my artboards need to have. They have to be the size necessary for printing. I want the effect to be purely for viewing, as shown in these images.

What I want:
[image: Stationery 1]

What I have:
[image]

Is this at all possible? I have tried looking for an answer on the internet but all I get is changing the actual size of my artboards. Thanks.

Comment: Are the envelope, the letterhead and the business cards on different artboards?

Answer (score 2):

### Adobe Acrobat DC

If the envelope, the letterhead and the business cards are on different artboards open your pdf in Acrobat:

```
File > Properties > Initial View
```

and set:

---

`Navigation tab:` Page Only *(or Bookmarks Panel and Page)*

`Page layout:`      **Single Page**

`Magnification:`  **Fit Width**

---

[image: Document Properties Initial View]

then save:

```
File > Save
```

and close:

```
File > Close
```

reopen the pdf from recent documents:

```
File > 1 my_document.pdf
```

---

### Adobe Acrobat Reader DC

Open your pdf in Acrobat Reader:

```
Edit > Preferences > Page Display > Default Layout and Zoom
```

---

`Page layout:` **Single Page**

`Zoom:`              **Fit Width**

---

[image: Document Preferences Override Page Display]

and than in:

```
Edit > Preferences > Accessibility > Override Page Display
```

---

`Always use Zoom Setting:` **Fit Width**

---

then save and reopen the pdf.

Comment: I am working with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. I don't have the initial view option in my properties. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @Bianca I have updated the answer, try with this

Comment: Still doesn't seem to accomplish what I want. I don't want the page layout to be single page. I want to have one long column with all my pages the same width, like in the image I show. With single page when I zoom out, I still only see one page at a time, just very small, with the next page appearing when I scroll down.  I want to be able to zoom out an see all my pages together in that column when I scroll down.

Comment: @Bianca If you want to have the possibility to show all the elements with the same width together, I suggest you to create an ad hoc presentation (maybe with a mockup)